# Question regarding TCP Connection Forcefully shut down

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I am designing a Client Server Chat application in Java which uses TCP connection between them. I am not able to figure out how to detect at server side when a client forcefully closes down. I need this as i am maintaining a list of online clients and i need to remove user from the list when he forcefully closes the connection.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Tara Singh

Comment: Did you find any of these helpful? Please return to your questions and keep them updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to receive timely notification of a disconnect is to attempt to send a small piece of information at regular intervals.  Then, the latest that you'll know of a client disconnect is at most your interval.  People call this a heartbeat.

Comment: Thank You for this suggestion. I did implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your server is using a java.net.Socket, you can query the socket from time to time, it provides methods isClosed() and isConnected().

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're handling your socket I/O

For example, if you're using a selector (java.nio) to do non-blocking I/O on a set of sockets you're going to find out about any disconnects the next time you call select().

Maybe if you updated your question with how you're handling the sockets?